# How to differentiate week, month, quarter year and full year from dates retreived from sql

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am making a attendance system for a company, I have 2 years worth of dates of about 120 employees, now what i have to do is that i have to differentiate based on those dates, like for example -

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h1>Attendence Sheet of $var</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>In-Time</th>
    <th>Todays_Date</th>
    <th>Entry_Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:02:32</td>
    <td>12/03/2017</td>
    <td>PRESENT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09:34:11</td>
    <td>12/03/2017</td>
    <td>LATE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:05:48</td>
    <td>12/03/2017</td>
    <td>HALFDAY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:27:58</td>
    <td>12/03/2017</td>
    <td>ABSENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above is example of the table i am retrieving data from.

Now if i retrieve all data of an employee, i want to sort it into weeks or months etc based on the date column, as per the user requests, how to do so?

This is the short version of what i want to do, so if you don't understand the question or what i want, leave an comment i will try my best to explain.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: how do you retrieve the data? Can you provide your code?

Comment: Via MySQL, Using SELECT query to get t_date where id=$_SESSION['id'].